# Is there a tool to tell me how much data my web application is getting from the database

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database, browser

I am creating a MVC web application using Visual Studio 2013 and was wondering if there is a tool to tell me how much data is being retrieved on each page when a request is made?

Is there something like this in a browser extension like firebug or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Glimpse maybe? Have a look at http://getglimpse.com and see if that will help.